# Android :unable to play video

Tags: android

I am working in android. I just used a video player. I am accessing video from my sdcard.

When i access video from myFolder then it works fine, but there are some folder which name are Japanese character. So whenever i want to access video from those folder then "Sorry, This video can not play" error is occurred.

This is my code which i am using:-

```
    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoId);
    MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
    controller.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 55);

    video.setVideoPath(URLDecoder.decode(sdCardUrl));
    video.setMediaController(controller);
    video.requestFocus();
    video.start();
```

and this my path in which i am facing problem to video:-

```
url = /sdcard/.FileStorage/History/Myfilestorage/のフダ名/H.264(avc)_mp3_1000kbps_640x480_25fps.mp4
```

please suggest what should i do ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem to trace the sequence of output of each line. I have done mistake that there is no need to decode url.

So the solution is to use following line:-
 **video.setVideoPath(sdCardUrl);**

in place of **video.setVideoPath(URLDecoder.decode(sdCardUrl));**

Answer (score 0):

Try by converting that Japanese name in to UTF-8 format and then try to use it.